# Invisible two buttons using xpath in Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In `sale.order` form view, there are two buttons `Send by Email`. One for `draft` state and another for `sent, sale`. I need to hide both buttons. I tried below code:

```xml
   <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_quotation_send']" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
   </xpath>
```

The result is: The button in `draft` state become invisible, another button is still visible.

How can I hide that button too?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code how it is, to hide both buttons by replacing with nothing.

```xml
<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_quotation_send']" position="replace"/>
<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_quotation_send']" position="replace"/>
```

I know it looks weird cause its exactly the same code twice but it worked for me.

Comment: I don't think so it will work. Your code will always apply to first button. It will never goes to another/second button.

Comment: It does, im using this to hide exactly those two buttons. As soon as i replace the first button with nothing, the second xpath will call the second button because the first one is not available any longer.

Answer (score 0):

We have to set attribute for both buttons.

Try with following code:

```
<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_quotation_send' and @states='sent']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="states" /> <!-- delete states attribute, it's influencing invisible behaviour -->
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</xpath
<xpath expr="//button[@name='action_quotation_send' and @states='draft']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="states" /> <!-- delete states attribute, it's influencing invisible behaviour -->
    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but might help someone in future.

```
<xpath expr="(//button[@name='action_quotation_send'])[1]" position="attributes">
...
</xpath>
<xpath expr="(//button[@name='action_quotation_send'])[2]" position="attributes">
...
</xpath>
```

Refer [How can you identify multiple elements with the same name in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/322021/1472458)